# Why does Gorm not recognize mongo domain class in Grails 4?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

Grails 4.0.10.  Mongodb 5.0.9 Community.

I'm following the instructions at https://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/ with a Grails Plugin project.

First anomaly, build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:mongodb:7.3.0'
```

Once I do this I get dependency errors and also have to add

```
compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:4.7.0'
compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.7.0'
```

Ok, everything else is pretty much a vanilla project.  I created a test domain class "QtxResponse" as

```
@Entity
class QtxResponse {

    static mapWith = "mongo"

    String objectId

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        //id column: "object_id"
        objectId index: true
    }
}
```

The project fires up without error.  Using the console I create a new QtxResponse via create-domain-class with a String objectId property and try to save it.  This is what I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either class [domainobject.qualtrics.QtxResponse] is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before calling any methods on a GORM entity.
```

What is this telling me? Is it something with Gorm setup or something with mapping to mongodb? I have tried both with and without Hibernate.

Comment: Should your id type be `org.bson.types.ObjectId` with appropriate import?

Comment: Hmmm.  I think it should be.

Comment: Yes, it should be.  That said, my main problem is still that QtxResponse is not regarded as a GORM entity.  Further info - I am using Intellij to create and edit the plugin.  I am familiar with Grails 4 - I have 5 apps and 7 plugins running with Grails 4.0.10.  However, I am completely new to mongodb, and it shows.

Comment: Ah!  Looks like plugin 7.3.0 requires Grails 5!  Dialing it back...

Answer (score 0):

For Grails 4.0.10, this configuration worked (with hibernate):

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:mongodb:6.1.7'
compile 'org.mongodb:bson:4.7.0'

compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.0.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.3.Final"
```